# Keeping Node.js results from spawn process in order

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

I have been working with Node.js lately, and I am having a problem finding a way to track the results of a child process stdout back to the request.

I have a list of hostnames in a file, my application reads the file, uses a simple regex to pull the hostnames from the file one line at a time, using split. Then I create an array of hostnames. Then for each hostname in the array I build an arguments string, and spawn a process using that argument string, however, I have no way of accessing the counting variable "i" from inside the process, and I cannot find a way to track the results back to the input.

my program should take each hostname and call snmp using "child process", then it should create and array of {hostname : "snmp-result"}, and lastly once that is done, save the array to a file.

I am using this program to try and pull serial numbers off of network gear. I have rewritten this code about 5 times, and I have even tried it with a function nested inside the spawn process instead of an on data event emitter, however I am at a loss. The relevent code is below:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').exec;
var split = require('split');
var fs = require('fs');
var snRe = '"(.*?)"';
var devRe = "(junos\\-([a-z]|[0-9])+\\-([a-z]|[0-9])+$)";
var devices = [];
var output = [];
var outfile = fs.createWriteStream('vri.txt',{'flags':'w'});
var infile = fs.createReadStream('devices',{flags: 'r', encoding: 'utf8'})
var spawnCmd = "/usr/local/bin/snmpwalk -v2c -c public"
var oid = ".1.3.6.1.4.1.2636.3.1.3"

function getSerial(callback) {

    for (var i=0;i<devices.length;i++) {
            var argument = spawnCmd + " " + devices[i] + " " + oid;
            ps = spawn(argument);
            ps.stdout.on('data',function(buf) {
                    if (buf) {
                            output.push(devices[i] + ": " + (buf.match(snRe))[1] +"\n");
                    }
                    else {
                    output.push('could not be reached');
                    }
                    })
                    //console.log(i + devices[i] + ": " + output[i] + '\n');
            }
    }
callback();
}

getDevices(function() {
    getSerial(function() {
            for (var i=0;i<output.length;i++) {
    outfile.write(output[i]);

}
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because of the async nature of spawn process, you cannot use a for loop to tackle such a program. Recursion is your friend here.

```
var spawn = require('child_process').exec;
var max = 3;

function genSerial(bufs, callback) {
  if(bufs.length === max) {
    callback(null, bufs);
    return;
  }
  var ps = spawn('sleep 1; date');
  ps.stdout.on('data',function(buf) {
    console.log(buf);
    bufs.push(buf);
    genSerial(bufs, callback);
  });
}

genSerial([], function(err, bufs) {
  console.log('showing buffers', bufs);
});
```

and the output is

```
benny@benny-VirtualBox:~/Documents/so$ node test.js 
Fri Jan 17 06:54:58 NZDT 2014

Fri Jan 17 06:54:59 NZDT 2014

Fri Jan 17 06:55:00 NZDT 2014

showing buffers [ 'Fri Jan 17 06:54:58 NZDT 2014\n',
  'Fri Jan 17 06:54:59 NZDT 2014\n',
  'Fri Jan 17 06:55:00 NZDT 2014\n' ]
```

Comment: It honestly never occurred to me to do it this way. Node is really my first delve into asynchronous programming. Looking at your solution a light just went off. This is one of those moments where not only is my question answered but you start thinking about how this will completely change the way I look at problems.

Comment: Glad to help. To get more accustomed to async programming, you can check out http://www.slideshare.net/cacois/nodejs-patterns-for-discerning-developers or other similar stuff